# React native expo - iOS app is terminated immediately when I press the Home button

Tags: react-native, expo

I wrote an iOS app in React Native(Expo). It's working well in Foreground but when I press Home button and the app is minimized, it's terminated immediately and it starts from the beginning when the app comes back to foreground.

Comment: please share logs and code to understand the error

Comment: The app doesn't have any error. The issue is just when the app is minimized for a minute and come back to foreground, the app restarts.
I think the timers cause this problem. What do you think?

Comment: could you please share your code ?